# Firebase query removing all elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query data using firebase filters and then I would like to remove only the results of that query, but I don't know why is removing all elements from that ref.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
ref.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToFirst(3).once('value', (snapshot) => {
   snapshot.ref.remove()
});
```

This query is removing all users, not only the first 3.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snapshot's `ref` property points to `'users'` - the location from which the first 3 elements were queried. Calling `remove` on that ref will remove all elements, as the query has no effect on the `remove` call.

You need to iterate the elements in the snapshot and call `remove` on each element's ref:

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
ref.orderByChild('timestamp')
  .limitToFirst(3)
  .once('value', snapshot => snapshot.forEach(child => child.ref.remove()));
```